# retrieve data from DB and mail it as Excel sheet using php

Tags: php, sql-server

Below is my code to mail the data from DB. Please help me for the corrections.

```
<?

set_time_limit(0);

require("..\class\mime_mail.inc");

unlink("filename.html");

`php -q D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\abc\xyz\getdata.php > filename.html`;

$to = "abc@xyz.com";   
$bcc = "abc@xyz.com";


$subject = 'aaaaaa - ' . date("Y-m-d");
$body = join('',file("filename.html"));
$headers  = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: abc@abc.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc:". $bcc ." \r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

In the above code, getdata.php is a file which retrieves the data from DB and stores in a Excel sheet. It's working fine. The above code is another file called senddata.php. When I run the senddata.php, I am supposed to receive the mail but not in the above case. Please help....

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it give you an error message? A blank screen? Just not send the email? Have you tried sending to different email accounts? Have you checked the SMTP logs to see if it's sent? Is it in the spam folder on your account?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your php.ini has the correct SMTP settings for sending mail. Can you send normal text mails?

Three comments about the code:

- `$body = join('',file("filename.html"));` PHP>=5 has `file_get_contents`: `$body = file_get_contents('filename.html');`
- `php -q D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\abc\xyz\getdata.php > filename.html;` '>' Already clears the file content, so there's probably no need to `unlink` it
- Prefer `<?php` over `<?` - this makes your code more portable

Comment: Hi Steffen, I tried sending a text mail and it's working fine. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Add ```$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type...```. Also consider using http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime.